# Select Data using mapping table data value Dynamically

Tags: sql

I have A mapping table which i have DatacolumnName. here's is mapping table data

```
ID  CustomObjectID  ObjectFieldName DataColumnName  CustomerID  UserID  IsActive    CustomObjectName
1047    2074        CompanyName       Column_1          18        17       1         CompanyObject
1049    2074          Email           Column_3          18        17       1        CompanyObject
1050    2074       CompanyPhone       Column_4          18        17       1        CompanyObject
1051    2074    CompanyBranch          Column_5         18         17       1        CompanyObject
1052    2074       BranchCode           Column_6        18         17       1         CompanyObject
1053    2074        City               Column_7         18         17       1         CompanyObject
1054    2074    PostalCode             Column_8         18         17       1         CompanyObject
1055    2074    Country                Column_9         18         17       1          CompanyObject
```

and My Data Table Record is Another table and table name is CustomData

```
Column_1    Column_3    Column_4    Column_5    Column_6    Column_7    Column_8    Column_9
Software    umar@gmail  03115171558  Miami       123         LA         786345test    USA1
```

But I need to show data in header using mapping table value (ObjectFieldName) like

```
CompanyName Email       CompanyPhone  CompanyBranch BranchCode   City      PostalCode   Country
Software    umar@gmail  03115171558       Miami      123         LA         786345test    USA1
```

i need to show data using these headers. everytime tablemapping column changed so i need to done dynamically. if anybody help me please.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: you need to do it using dynamic sql , syntax will be depend on which dbms you are using

Comment: I am using SQL DBMS and this issue need to be done in my SQL stored procedure

Comment: do you mean you are using `oracle` ?

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL DBMS"

Answer (score 0):

i have resolved this issue and i am sharing my sql script if anyone faces same sort of issue , can get an idea from the script that i have shared.

```
declare @count int
declare @temp table (id int not null primary key identity(1,1) ,customdataid int, columnname varchar(max), fieldname varchar(max))
insert into @temp
select CustomObjectID, DataColumnName , ObjectFieldName from CustomObjectMappingTable
set @count = @@ROWCOUNT
declare @Coulmnname varchar(max) , @fieldname nvarchar(max)
while @count > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT  @Coulmnname = columnname , @fieldname = fieldname 
        FROM @temp
        WHERE id=@count
        declare @mergeColumnname varchar(max) = @Coulmnname + ' AS ' + @fieldname
        declare @coltable table (ColumnNames Nvarchar(max))
        insert into @coltable values ( '' + @mergeColumnname +'')
        
    SET @count = @count - 1; -- Countdown
END
--select * from  @coltable
 DECLARE @cols NVARCHAR(MAX), @query1 NVARCHAR(MAX) , @DataValues NVARCHAR(max);
SET @cols = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ','+ColumnNames FROM @coltable c  FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '');
Declare @UpdateColumnQuery nvarchar(max)
SET @UpdateColumnQuery = 'select CustomobjectSchemaID , DataID , ' + @cols + ' from customdata where CustomObjectSchemaID = ' + CAST(@CustomObjectSchemaId As nvarchar(20)) 
EXEC( @UpdateColumnQuery )
```